# how to trigger a react-native app to wake up? (for alarm)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile-development

Basically I am trying to add an alarm feature to my app.

**set time & date, save** >> **turn the app off** >> when it's the time, **RING-RING-!**

But to do this, the app should wake itself to run the alarm feature; otherwise it won't work unless the app is running at the alarm time.

Any regular alarm apps just open itself when its the time, even when the app was not running on the phone.  does anyone here know how apps self-wake?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Use AlarmManager to do alarm envenif the app is not running.
But if the machine reboot, it will not work. So we need to run a service to register alarm when machine boot complete.